# Opencv3.3 VS2015 Release can run, but Debug can't

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2015

Today I do some opencv in VS2015, when Release mode it can run, but in Debug mode it always has wrong, the program can't work ok, has two windows(namedWindow&imshow), and the waitKey() can't work ok too.

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>  
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>  

using namespace cv;

int main() {

Mat img = imread("pic.jpg");

namedWindow("gg");

imshow("gg", img);

waitKey(0);
}
```

**Release:**
The program '[3912] TestOpencv.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

**Debug:**
Exception thrown at 0x0000000077403290 (ntdll.dll) in TestOpencv.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000CF18F000C28.
The program '[4188] TestOpencv.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Are you linking the debug mode executable with debug mode OpenCV libs? If you mix them up it usually ends like this, since the two runtimes are not interchangeable.

Comment: I solved this problem by updataing VS2015->New Project->Installed->Templates->Visual C++, anyway, thankyou for your advice.